# Inserting data from SQL to Laravel seed file

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-workbench, seeding

I have several pre-populated tables in MySQL Workbench, and I desire to move the data from those tables into the tables, I created using migrations in Laravel. I read that you use seed files to insert data but the documentation doesn't really go over this aspect.

E.G.: one of my tables in SQL looks like:

`id     |   course
1      |   CHEMISTRY 101
2      |   BIOLOGY 101
3      |   ENGINEERING 101
//etc`

Now this is defined in SQL, but I would like to move this data into my migration/seed file for my courses table. How would I go about doing this an easy and fast way, without having to manually enter data?

Comment: MySQL can easily dump the data to a CSV file. From there you could import that data in the seeder. Or if the data is fairly simple you could just use a macro in your text editor to get it into the right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL Workbench you can [export the data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html).

> Use [the] wizard to either export or import SQL generated from MySQL
>   Workbench or with the **mysqldump** command.

This will create detailed database and table operations, standard backup/restore behavior using the mysqldump command and meta data, includes control over how data is handled, and includes meta data

Answer (score 2):

I have came up with a custom but quick solution for this. If you have only a simple mysql database and a seed file, then you can do the followings:

1. export data from phpmyadmin.
2. select php array format as output format.
3. then copy paste the array to seed file